# Timer in C++11 with chrono: from nanoseconds to milliseconds

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I would like to know the milliseconds a function took. I am using chrono like this:

```
chrono::system_clock::time_point start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// big_function ...

cout << "Function took: " << chrono::nanoseconds(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << "nanosec" << endl;
```

This prints: `"Function took: 32423212131321 nanosec"`
Is there any way to print milliseconds instead of nanosconds ?

Comment: My -1 for you not even searching for online help, which would have given you an instant answer.

Comment: high_resolution_clock should be avoided. Use steady_clock. See this note at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock): "different standard library implementations, and its use should be avoided. It is often just an alias for std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock, but which one it is depends on the library or configuration. When it is a system_clock, it is not monotonic (e.g., the time can go backwards). For example, for gcc's libstdc++ it is system_clock, for MSVC it is steady_clock, and for clang's libc++ it depends on configuration."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast)

```
chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>
       (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count()
```

Comment: +1 And more information.  `duration_cast` will truncate towards zero.  If you would like some other rounding mode, use one of these utilities:  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_util.html  They allow you to round towards +/- infinity or to nearest.

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>
    (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count()
```

or

```
(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start) / chrono::milliseconds(1)
```

Note that your version is not portable: you'd need a cast to convert to nanoseconds, if the clock had a higher precision.